# Ubuntu says disk is smaller than it actually is

Tags: partitioning, grub2, mount

This is an issue my friend is having, but I understand his problem well.

He needed more space on his partition, but he had to move the starting point backwards in order to make more space. That was pretty much impossible, so what he did instead is

- Create a new partition, that is 200gb
- Use dd to clone his old partition to that new partition

It boots successfully, and it says the 200gb partition is mounted at `/`, but the file manager says that `/` only has 100gb. We tried writing a huge file to it, and it said "No more disk space" at 100gb.

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SSD PLUS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3abc5c13

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 1367191551 1367189504 651.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       1757814784 1952526335  194711552  92.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3       1952526336 1953523711     997376   487M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb4  *    1367191552 1757814783  390623232 186.3G 83 Linux
```

And the output of `lsblk`

```
sdb    8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
|
 -sdb1 8:17   0  651.9G 0 part
 -sdb2 8:18   0  92.9G  0 part
 -sdb3 8:19   0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
 -sdb4 8:20   0  186.3G 0 part /
```

(weird formatting because my friend made me type it out myself for some reason)

Comment: You don't clone a partition into another partition. Had that happened the old partition would be gone and any cloned partition has the exact same size as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I learned about a tool called `resize2fs`, and that was what I needed to fix it.

`resize2fs /dev/sdxY`